# Placing a detail component in Revit using python

Tags: python, components, revit-api

I'm trying to create detail component buttons that run the following code. However, I need it to work for 2015-2018 possibly 2019 in the future.

Currently I have the custom ribbon and buttons made, but I can't get this script to work due to `commandData` in the first line not working. I've tried testing this as a `macro` just to try and see if it will work first before continuing.

```
FamilySymbol symbol = GetElements<FamilySymbol> (commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Document)
                          .Where(item => item.Name == "NameYouWant")
                          .First();
commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.PromptForFamilyInstancePlacement(symbol);
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the collection of elements of the specified type.
    /// <para>The specified type must derive from Element, or you can use Element but you get everything :)</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of element to get</typeparam>
    /// <returns>The list of elements of the specified type</returns>
    public IEnumerable<T> GetElements<T>(Document document) where T : Element
    {
        FilteredElementCollector collector = new FilteredElementCollector(document);
        collector.OfClass(typeof(T));
        return collector.Cast<T>();
    }
```

It's located in the Detail Items in the project browser

```
Family = Break Line
Type   = Break Line
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `commandData` argument is a parameter passed into the `Execute` method of an external command by Revit. It includes data enabling the external command to get in touch with Revit and its database.

A macro provides a different method to access Revit and its database.

Work through the [Revit API getting started material](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#2) or the [Revit developer guide hello world walkthroughs](http://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2019/ENU/?guid=Revit_API_Revit_API_Developers_Guide_Introduction_Getting_Started_Walkthroughs_html) to see how to set up an external command to get the `commandData` passed in as required.